# Laravel 5.4 "MethodNotAllowedHttpException" (Basic Task List)

Tags: php, forms, laravel, routes

i was trying to follow [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/quickstart#installation) tutorial on Laravel, even though most of the code & directories there were outdated, i managed to make the "Add Task" and also The Form to show up after a few errors.

now the problem, the delete button.
when i click on it, it shows a "MethodNotAllowedHttpException".
i changed the source code to match the newest version of Laravel.

my form (current version) :

```
<form action="{{ url('/task/'.$task->id) }}" method="POST">
   {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
   {{ csrf_field() }}
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
     <i class="fa fa-btn fa-trash"></i>Delete
   </button>
</form>
```

my route :

```
Route::delete('/task/{id}', function ($id) {
    Task::findOrFail($id)->delete();
    return redirect('/');
});
```

i've been trying to fix this for 4 hours now, changing the methods of my route and form; but to no avail.
this is my first question on this site, sorry if there's something wrong in this question.

thanks~

edit:
to further help the effort, here's the complete error log
[Error log, in Google Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWNoa.png)

Comment: You should use method="post" and then use the helper "method field" as you have already done

Comment: @ClaudioLudovicoPanetta thanks for the fast response, but changing both from "delete" to "post" made the delete button behave like the "add task" button from the tutorial; as it's returning a validation error ("the name field is required") rather than actually deleting the 'task' from the Database.

Comment: You dont need `{{method_field('delete')}}` when you are already passing the hidden field of `_method`

Comment: @StephenHendricks thank you for the comment, i excluded out the "method_field", and also "_method" interchangeably, choosing one or the other; but still not fixed.

Comment: We don't do [solved] edits here, would you add a self-answer instead? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer :
Turns out the problem lies in the Database-table itself, let me explain :
i was referring to a 'tasks' table that is referred as 'task' in code (no problem)
BUT, i was referring to a column called "ID" in my table as "id" in my code, creating the error (a rookie mistake).

thanks to @Autista_z for the pointer, and everyone else below for the guidance!

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
<form action="{{ url('task/'.$task->id) }}" method="DELETE">
```

to

```
<form action="{{ url('task/'.$task->id) }}" method="POST">
```

Because form method DELETE does not exist, Laravel just "overwrites" this method with the hidden input "method" (you can place this input using "`{{ method_field('DELETE') }}`").

Comment: thanks for the answer, i tried changing the method of the form from "DELETE" to "POST", and it returned the same 'MethodNotAllowedHttpException" error; when i click on the "Delete Button"

Comment: @Kevinfu could you check if the form action url is correct? is the helper function url() creating correct url?

Comment: sorry, but I'm new to Laravel and web development in general; and i believe that the URL that i entered is correct (i followed the tutorial).

Comment: Not exactly, in the tutorial is url vithout this function and with "/" common slash in the begining. If thats not the problem. Because everithing else is ok.

Comment: Thank you soo much, after reading your comment and though of the possibility that it was the URL (because the methods used are all right), i went to the Database and checked the table

turns out the field "id" doesn't exist; instead it was "ID", after changing the column name in my database-table; it worked!

thanks mate! :D

Answer (score 0):

Form dosent support method Delete or Put ... It support only get and post methods, if You want implement delete in laravel this article will help you
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28634798/how-can-i-delete-a-post-resource-in-laravel-5)

Comment: i tried method spoofing "Delete" into the form, still returns the same error sadly...

Comment: turns out it was the URL, and how my database-table was set-up.
thanks for the help anyways, learned a lot from reading your link!